# Как разделить массив на 2 части и вывести их

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть массив 'abcd' Как можно его разделить чтобы в консоль был результат 'ab' , 'cd'
У меня есть такой код, но он пока выводит 'ab'

```
let array = 'abcd'
console.log(array.split('').slice(0,2))
```

Comment: У вас не массив, а строка. Только переменная называется array, это её массивом не делает. Впрочем, `slice(0,2)` забирает 2 символа из строки, начиная с нулевого. Думаю, справитесь с тем, чтобы взять ещё 2 символа, начиная со второго.

Comment: ```console.log([array.substring(0, 2), array.substring(2)])```

Comment: .split() разбивает строк на массив, не так разве?

Comment: @kibork, виноват. всё верно. Вам уже подсказали, как забрать оставшуюся часть букв из строки.

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо

Comment: array.split('', 2) будет аналогом вашего кода выше)